# How to switch between 2 browsers in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser

I'm working on selenium webdriver with java. I want to open a browser perform some actions in it. Then open another browser and do the same actions in it, then go back to first browser and perform some actions.

How can i switch between 2 browsers (not the switching between 2 tabs)?

This is what i have done:

```
@BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() throws BiffException, IOException,InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\MyProjects\\SeleniumTrials\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(properties.getProperty("VAR_BASEURL"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
      WebDriver  tempDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        tempDriver.get(properties.getProperty("VAR_BASEURL"));
        tempDriver.manage().window().maximize();
}
@Test
    public void playTournament() throws InterruptedException, BiffException,IOException {
    int rowNumber = 1;
    int newRowNumber=2;
    WebElement login =driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_LOGIN"))); 
    login.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_USERNAME")));
    username.clear();
    username.sendKeys(getCellContent(0, rowNumber));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_PASSWORD")));
    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, rowNumber));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement continueButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_CONTINUE")));
    continueButton.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

   WebElement login =tempDriver .findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_LOGIN"))); 
   login.click();
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   WebElement username = tempDriver .findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_USERNAME")));
   username.clear();
   username.sendKeys(getCellContent(0, rowNumber));
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   WebElement password = tempDriver .findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_PASSWORD")));
   password.clear();
   password.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, rowNumber));
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   WebElement continueButton = tempDriver .findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_CONTINUE")));
   continueButton.click();
```

Comment: How do you open the second browser? by using `new ChromeDriver()` again?

Comment: yes.. opened the second browser using new ChromeDriver() again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

You reinitialize the `driver` instance, witch means you loose the first browser. You can see it by calling `getWindowHandles()`

```
driver.getWindowHandles(); // will be 1, the last open browser
```

If you want to different browsers use temporary driver

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriver tempDriver = new ChromeDriver();

// do some stuff on tempDriver

tempDriver.close();

// continue working with the first driver
```

Comment: But the user is getting logged into only in the second browser

Comment: how do you know the user is not logged into the first browser? Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes... i'm getting an error. There is a slight mistake in the previous comment. User is  logged in through the first browser. I am getting an error in the line : WebElement login =tempDriver .findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_LOGIN")));                The error is : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]"}

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: I can access the URL and other texts in the second browser. But cannot access the objects in that. Please suggest a solution

Comment: Hi, Finally it worked. There was a small mistake in my code. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for,

1. keep two browser objects
2. define a method which does a set of operations on a browser
3. call this method first using the first browser and again using the second browser
4. then perform some more action on the first browser

Comment: Yes.. This is what i want to do. How can i do this?

Comment: Hey, did you found any solution for your problem, i also need to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

### I have solved switching between browser drivers in a Typescript but it should be easy for you to understand the methodology and implement it in the Java.

@TDriver.ts

```
    import {browser, ProtractorBrowser} from 'protractor';

    export class TDriver {
      private static defaultBrowser: ProtractorBrowser = browser;
      private static activeBrowser;

      public async newDriver() {
        const secondDriver = TDriver.activeBrowser.forkNewDriverInstance();
        await this.setActiveBrowser(secondDriver);
        }

      public setActiveBrowser(driver: ProtractorBrowser) {
        TDriver.activeBrowser = driver;
      }

      public getActiveBrowser() {
        return TDriver.activeBrowser;
      }

      public setDefaultBrowserActive() {
        TDriver.activeBrowser = TDriver.defaultBrowser;
      }

    }
```

@Test.ts

```
import {by} from 'protractor';
import {TDriver} from '../driver/TDriver';

export class Test {
  private driver = new TDriver().getActiveBrowser();

   this.driver.findElement(by.xpath("xPathSelector")).click(); //this click in first native driver instance

   await new TDriver().newDriver(); //create new driver and switch to it!

   this.driver.findElement(by.xpath("xPathSelector")).click(); //this click in the second driver instance

   await new TDriver().setDefaultBrowserActive(); //now we switch and use again native driver

   this.driver.findElement(by.xpath("xPathSelector")).click(); //this click in first native driver instance
}
```

Those methods enables you to perform test in native browser then create new instance and continue test in second browser driver. Works in my project.