# How to switch my IE browser session to chrome browser session?

Tags: java, selenium

My 'sign in' is in IE browser and after sign in if i click on the links they get opened in chrome browser. How to switch my current browser from IE to chrome during the same Test case. If i create a instance of chrome driver, it opens a new browser altogether and if i use getWindowHandles to get chrome browser count, it gives one. It didn't recognize the chrome browser opened by the IE browser. Please guide me.

I thought opening a new instance of chrome driver would solve my problem but it doesn't let me go to the session created through IE browser chrome browser.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373746/how-to-switch-between-2-browsers-in-selenium-webdriver-with-java) can help.

Comment: This opens a new chrome browser but i want to continue from the chrome browser opened through IE browser. As there will be two chrome browser opened, one from the chrome instance and other through IE browser link that i clicked on in the Test Case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot do it with Selenium as the driver instance, once created, remains with the same browser until quit.
Firstly, have you set you default browser on PC as IE browser? In that case, the new links may also get opened with IE browser so handling windows/tabs would work.